# Expose internal IP so it can be accessed from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I just deployed nginx on a K8S Node in a cluster, the master and worker communicate using **internal** IP address.

I can `curl http://worker_ip:8080` (nginx) from internal network, but how to make it can be accessed from **external/internet** network?

Or should I use public IP as my node host?

Comment: in addition to NodePort answer you need to read this https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the service type to NodePort. grab the nodePort that is assigned to the service.
you should be able to access nginx using host:nodeport

see below for reference

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```